# Calling ajax several times result a duplicated response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created an ajax function that returns my items Price by fetching from my DB. I'm sure there isn't any problem with my php but sometimes I get the same result twice!

jQuery

```
$('.removemore___').click(function(e) {
  var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item');
  var col_id = $(this).attr('data-col');
  var value = $(this).attr('data-value');

  if ($(this).attr('data-trash') == 'trash') {
    newPopuper('alert_sure__', 'flex', 'blackScreen');
    $('.__aggtoyes').attr('data-item', item_id);
    $('.__aggtoyes').attr('data-col', col_id);
    $('.__aggtoyes').attr('data-value', value);
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/chekavailableitem.php?remove",
      data: {
        item_id: item_id,
        col_id: col_id,
        value: value
      },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response) {
        var iNum = parseInt(value);
        iNum--;
        if (response == 'done') {
          $('.value__cart[data-item=' + item_id + '][data-col=' + col_id + ']').html(iNum);
          $('.removemore___[data-item=' + item_id + '][data-col=' + col_id + ']').attr('data-value', iNum);
          $('.addmore___[data-item=' + item_id + '][data-col=' + col_id + ']').attr('data-value', iNum);
          if (iNum == 1) {
            location.reload();
          }
        } else if (response == 'deleted') {
          location.reload();
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#wrong-signup').html(': 102');
      },
      timeout: 5000
    });
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/get_finalize_cart.php",
    data: {},
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      // var final_price = $.parseJSON(response)
      console.log(response);
      if (response[0] == 'done') {
        $('.final_price__').html(response[1] + ' <span style="font-size: .786rem;font-weight: 400">تومان</span>');
      } else {
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#wrong-signup').html(': 101');
    },
    timeout: 5000
  });
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Here is full function in jQuery

```
<?php 
    include 'db.php';
    include 'function.php';

    $user_id = extractUserId();
    $chekcart = "SELECT * FROM `box` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'";
    $result_cox_cart_cheker = connectANDdie($chekcart);
    $sum_price = 0;
    while($row_items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cox_cart_cheker)){
        $price = $row_items['item_price'];
        $value = $row_items['value'];
        $sum_price = $sum_price  + ( $price*$value );

    $final_value = number_format($sum_price);
    $result = ['done',$final_value];
    $result1 = json_encode($result);

    echo $result1;
}
```

and I'll also show a screenshot from console page so you can see what my result is:

[image: console pics]

[image: Network tab]

Comment: You must be sending them twice, check the Network tab of the console.

Comment: Tip: Use `dataType: 'json'` and it will call `JSON.parse()` automatically for you.

Comment: @Barmar ty but my problem is something else , i added a new image from my network tab

Comment: @Barmar its not sending twice actually it sends a duplicated result instead of a valid result example: it should send 15,000,000 but it sent 12,000,000 twice and never sent 15,000,000

Comment: Even if it sends two responses to one request, the code will only process one of them. So you must be sending two requests.

Comment: @Barmar its a buttom to change the number of item that client request to buy and higher number higher price this ajax job is to calculate (item_price * how many of that item client wants) and returns the result every time client clicked on + or - so im sending several request not only two it depends on how many times client click on + or - but some times it send a wrong result and i cheked the database it was ok so there is must be a problem on either php or js

Comment: If the user clicks a second time before the response is received, you'll send multiple requests. And they might not be processed in ordered. Try disabling the button until you get the response.

Comment: @Barmar actually i thought about this and i tried once clicking on the buttoms with a 5 seconds delay but i had the same problem! is there any professional way to make this delay with coding ? like loading ?

Comment: You need to show more code. You mention a button to + and -, how does this code fit in with that? Why doesn't the AJAX request for that return the new price, instead of using a separate call for it?

Comment: @Barmar i edited jquery part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not waiting for `chekavailableitem.php?remove` to complete before you call `get_finalize_cart.php`. Since AJAX is asynchronous, the latter might be processed first, so you'll get a duplicate of the old value.

You should put the second `$.ajax()` call in the `sucess:` function of the first `$.ajax()` call, or use a promise.

Comment: You are the legend ty man <3
also i added `global: false,` as i experienced an error when i use ajax inside another ajax <3